# Laravel 8.x - Form checkboxes to pivot table

Tags: php, html, laravel, eloquent

I am building a platform where students can apply for academic courses.
The students use a form to provide some personal information and then choose at least one course to apply for.

When the form is sent, the `ApplicationsController` validates the inputs and checks that there is at least one course checked. The **controller**:

```
public function student_store(Request $request, Course $course)
{

    $request->validate([

        'fname' => 'required|string|min:2|max:40',
        'lname' => 'required|string|min:2|max:40',
        'email' => 'required|email|min:6|max:254',
        'course-check' => 'required', 
        'phone' => 'required|digits:10',
        'created_at' =>  \Carbon\Carbon::now(), 
        'updated_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::now(),  
    
    ]);
```

If the validation is ok, a new `Applicant` is created in the database using the form inputs:

```
    $input = $request->all();
    Applicant::create($input);
```

However the **goal** is to also create one or more new instances in the pivot table `applicant_course`, depending on which one or more courses the student has selected. So far I have this:

```
          $applicant = Applicant::where('fname', $input['fname'] )
                                ->where('lname', $input['lname'] )
                                ->where('email', $input['email'] )
                                ->latest()->first();

          $checkboxes = $request->all('course-check');
          foreach ($checkboxes as $checkbox){
              $applicant->courses()->where('course_id', $checkbox)->attach($course->id);
          }
}
```

However, all that the controller function does, is to validate the inputs and create a new `Applicant` in the database with their data but nothing is added in the pivot table.

Here is the **view** structure (ignore the `$program` variables):

```
@foreach ($courses as $course)
@if ($course->program_id == $program->id)
<div class="course course-{{$program->id}}-{{$course->id}}">
    <div class="course-header">
        <label class="course-number" for="course-check-{{$program->id}}-{{$course->id}}">{{$program->id}}0{{$course->id}}0</label>
        <label class="course-title" for="course-check-{{$program->id}}-{{$course->id}}">{{$course->title}}</label>                                            
        <input type="checkbox" name="course-check[{{ $course->id }}]" class="course-check" id="course-check-{{$program->id}}-{{$course->id}}" value="" >
    </div>
</div>
@endif
@endforeach
```

Here is the `Applicant` **model**:

```
class Applicant extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'fname',
        'lname',
        'email',
        'phone',
    ];

    public function courses()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Course::class)->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

Can someone help ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to change checkbox name like below

```
<input type="checkbox" name="course-check[]" class="course-check" id="course-check-{{$program->id}}-{{$course->id}}" value="{{ $course->id }}" >
```

Then in controller

```
$checkboxes = $request->get('course-check');
$applicant->courses()->sync($checkboxes);
```

or

```
$checkboxes = $request->get('course-check');
$applicant->courses()->attach($checkboxes);
```

To know difference between attach and sync

Ref:https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: Thank you, this works! And thanks for putting the ref for the attach and sync methods. On a side note, do you think there is a better way to catch the newly created Applicant instead of querying the form input data and picking the last one ?

Comment: @BillM. Better pass $applicant id to view as hidden field input then you can find by applicant id.its more safer than finding latest first. if email is unique then no issues then no issue with the code